# Can I oil a squeaking tap?

Tags: taps

I have a tap with one handle for hot and cold water (not sure how to call it, it looks like the picture)
[image]

It worked good for about 2.5 years. But now, its handle became hard to turn and it makes squeaking sound when the handle is turned.

I wanted to oil it, but haven't found any hole where to put the oil.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it just the handle that squeaks?

Comment: @Freiheit yes, just the handle.

Comment: In that case use Greg Dolphs answer, but start by simply taking the handle off. In the picture shown, there should be a screw underneath that red/blue cap. you may get lucky and find its just a squeaky handle rather than the entire assembly.

Comment: @Freiheit Indeed, there is a screw underneath that cap. I opened the screw and tried to remove the handle, but didn't succeeded (don't know what that screw holds there :-\ ). So, I just put some oil  in the hole underneath the cap with hope it would help, but it didn't. (I did so before asking the question.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oil's no good, water will wash it away, use silicone grease.  You may be able to grease it up without taking it apart. Turn the water off, then lift the handle all the way up. Put a bit of grease on housing exposed when the handle is lifted, use a cotton swab to get into the gaps. Exercise the handle up and down and see if that gets rid of the squeak. If that doesn't work you are going to have to take it apart (look for an explosion diagram of your faucet online), take lots of photos and keep the parts in plastic containers to make sure you don't lose anything. Check the condition of the washers as worn washers may cause binding, hence a squeak. When putting it back together grease the parts that rub against one another as you go. Don't go overboard on the grease, a little goes a long way.

One word of caution: before taking anything apart it's important to realize that you may not be able to get it together again, and may require that you replace the faucet entirely. Some units are not meant to be maintained, may have plastic pieces that break and you can't get them back together, or may have proprietary washers or other parts that you can't buy replacements for. If it's broken already then you lose nothing by trying of course.

Comment: If you know the make and model of the faucet check the manufacturer or big-box home store website for a manual that will show you how to disassemble it.

Comment: Definitely, the internet is a great source for that.

Comment: You don't want oil in these as it can swell and rot the seal cups, plus it probably isn't good for you either if this is used for drinking water. Harvey's Silicone Grease is one product you can use, ask at any plumbing supply.